# How to query gaps and list lower/upper bounds of the gap in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I am struggling with listing the gaps including their lower and upper bounds in a simple SQLite table.

The table:

id

1

2

5

6

8

What I want is a result like (cnt is counting the missing integers):

lb  ub   cnt

2    5    2

6    8    1

I have already found the gaps, but no idea how to put lower and upper bounds together and count the missing integers:

SELECT  id
FROM    table mo
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    messages mi 
        WHERE   mi._id = mo._id + 1
        )
ORDER BY id

Replacing the condition with -1 I get the other bounds.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind your expected result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get the gaps with a subequery:

```
select t.id lb, t.next ub, (t.next - t.id - 1) cnt from (
  select 
    id, 
    (select min(id) from tablename where t.id < id) next
  from tablename t
  ) t
where t.next is not null and t.next - t.id > 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3VFbCqhJmD3Aq1VFWtYNmW/0)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a straightforward gaps and islands problem.

```
CREATE TABLE test(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1), (2), (5), (6), (8);
WITH ranges AS (SELECT id AS lb, lead(id, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS ub FROM test) 
SELECT lb, ub, ub - lb - 1 AS cnt FROM ranges WHERE ub - lb > 1;
```

gives

```
lb          ub          cnt       
----------  ----------  ----------
2           5           2         
6           8           1
```

(Note: The above requires Sqlite 3.25 or newer)